# Possible to make desktop icons bigger than max?

Tags: macos, icon, desktop, customization

I have my desktop icons set as big as they'll go... but would like them even bigger if possible!

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Would Sys Pref / Accessibility / Zoom help?

Comment: did you set the size using Show View Options?

Comment: @Andyroo not in my situation unfortunately but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Macintosh in the Finder. Once there be sure to display contents in icon view. Now while in Finder go to the View Menu and near the bottom select "Show view options". This brings up the panel shown below.

[image]

Move the top slider to the right for larger icons.  You may have to move the grid slider to increase spacing as well. You can experiment with these two sliders to get the default view you want.

Comment: Sorry but that's what I'd done already! maybe I need to look for some kind of plugin... thanks anyway though!

Comment: well if you do that some apps have icons as big as 1024x1024 you surely don't want them bigger than that.  That only fits a few on your desktop at once.  How big do you want the icons to be?